# Plotting graph using multiple Jquery sliders

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, graph, slider, flot

I am using multiple Jquery UI sliders to populate values onto a graph that i have plotted using Jquery FLot.
The problem i am facing is i need to set a maximum value for the graph and each slider contributes some value to the graph, i.e the graph populates cumulatively.
But every time i try to populate the graph using multiple sliders, the jquery slider gives erroneous values and the graph also populates with the multiple values. 
If I remove the logic and populate the graph using any of the sliders, then the graph gives me individual values. 
here is the part of code i am working upon:

```
var plot_val=0;
        function plot(val) {
        value_plot=val;

        var d2 = [[0, value_plot]];
        var d3 = [[0, value_plot/2]]
        var options_blue = {
                series: {color: '#0000ff',
                bars: { show: true,  barWidth :20*20}},
                  xaxis:  {show:false, min: 1} ,
                  yaxis:  { show:true,min: 0,max:500} 

              };
        var options_red = {
                series: {color: '#FF0000',
                bars: { show: true,  barWidth : 20*20}},
                  xaxis:  {show:false, min: 1} ,
                  yaxis:  { show:true,min: 0,max:500 } 

              };
        $.plot($("#placeholder"),  [d2],options_blue);
        $.plot($("#placeholder1"),  [d3],options_red);


    };

        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min_1" ).slider({
              range: "min",
              value: 1,
              min: 1,
              max: 500,
              slide: function( event, ui ) {

                plot(ui.value);
              }
             });
          });
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min_2" ).slider({
              range: "min",
              value: 1,
              min: 1,
              max: 500,
              values: [1,500],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {

                plot(ui.value);
               }
             });
          });
```

Comment: it can be done by using the jquery plugin for sliders and using the flot api. the exact process would be retrieving the value of the slider within the #slider-id('live','change') function and passing the value to the plot function used in the Flot api. What is surprising is that there is hardly any lag between the moving of the slider and the plotting of the graph. :)